# Google Apps Script to search for the artist and song name and return the release date

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm not sure if this is possible but I'm working on a project and I was wondering if there was a way to utilise google apps script to search for an artist (Column A) and song name (Column B) and return the year released in column C.
This data would then be used for some analysis and formulas.

I'm not very familiar with Google apps script but I know someone I work with has worked with it to pull in Lat/Long data from google maps.

Comment: First of all, please edit your question, add more information : what ? where from ? and where to ?  From your current question it is not understand what you want

Answer (score 0):

The following code will perform the search of the active sheet as described.

- Column A: Artist name
- Column B: Song title
- Column C: Release year

A text search of `Column A` finds all of the rows which match the artist.
The list of rows is filtered using `Column B` to match the song title and the value in `Column C` is returned.

```js
function getYearFromArtistNameAndSongTitle(artistName, songTitle) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Artist Name is in Column 'A'
  const artistColumn = sheet.getRange("A:A");
  const artistRows = artistColumn.createTextFinder(artistName).findAll();
  // Song Title is in Column 'B'
  function songTitleFilter(range) {
    return sheet.getRange("B" + range.getRow()).getValue().toString().toLowerCase() == songTitle.toLowerCase();
  }
  // Release Year is in Column 'C'
  return artistRows.filter(songTitleFilter).map((range) => sheet.getRange("C" + range.getRow()).getValue()).flat();
}


function demo() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const result = getYearFromArtistNameAndSongTitle("Imagine Dragons", "Believer");
  Logger.log(result);
  ui.alert("Found: " + result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns a 2d array for posting into a spreadsheet

```
function search(n, a) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const [, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();//assume header on row 1
  let o = vs.map(r => {
    if (r[0] == n && r[1] == a) {
      return r;
    }
  }).filter(e => e);
  o.unshift(["Name", "Artist", "Year"])
  if (o.length > 1) {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o));
    return o;//You post this return into a spreadsheet it is a 2d array
  } else {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify([`No records matched Name: ${n} Artist; ${a}`, ,]));
    return [`No records matched Name: ${n} Artist; ${a}`, ,]
  }
}
```